# I family shared all my games, but two of them say buy instead of play

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

My account that is sharing is not active nor is anyone else playing the game.
The two titles that wont allow me to play are Counter Strike: Source, and Half life 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Steam only showing me "Buy" instead of "Play" option for a game shared via Family Sharing?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208170/why-is-steam-only-showing-me-buy-instead-of-play-option-for-a-game-shared-vi)

Comment: The paragraph that starts with "There are some games" applies to your case.

Comment: @arda - I think this may be slightly different.  There is a bug/issue whereby if you bought valve games in a bundle they are not shareable.

Comment: @camelCase that makes sense then

Answer (score 2):

There are reports of Valve games being shareable when purchased independently.  However, the games appear to not be shareable when purchased as part of a bundle (e.g. Orange Box etc).

Sources:

https://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/1/792924412322347539/

> I have the same problem, also bought the HL2 series as a bundle.

http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/1/792923683632096521/

> I have a problem with this, but mine is happening on EVERY source game. did you buy the half life complete package? I bought them with valve complete pack. that might be the culprit. the bundled games. not sure though, valve has not responded to any of these posts. smh

http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/792923683796413789/?ctp=11

> Theres another topic about problem with games from bundles/packs.
>
> For exaple: CS:GO can be shared ONLY if was bought as single game.
>   If you bought Valve Complete Pack or Counter-Strike Complete Pack you CANT share games from it.
>
> Its verry annoying.
>   SFS started in year 2013 and they cant fix many EASY to fix THINGS.
>   Shame on You.... Valve. Shame - On - You.

Answer (score 1):

There are some games that cannot be played via family sharing. I know that H1Z1 is part of it of my own experience. Looks like CSS and HL2 are also part of that.